# Flask проблема с отображением символов кириллицы

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

Я пишу сервер на Flask, база данных MySQL, когда я вывожу таблицу на сайте, то символы кириллицы отображаются как символы юникода:

```json
{
    "posts": [{
        "body": "\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435 \u0441\u0438\u043c\u0432\u043e\u043b\u044b",
        "id": 8,
        "title": "\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442"
    }, {
        "body": "english symbols",
        "id": 9,
        "title": "test"
    }]
}
```

Я пытался указывать кодировку utf8 и отключение ASCII в JSON, но это не работает:

URI базы данных:

```
'mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost/api_test?auth_plugin=mysql_native_password&charset=utf8'
```

Создание экземпляра Flask:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Configuration)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
```

Код модели таблицы и функций:

```py
class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}:{}>".format(self.id,  self.title[:10])


@app.route('/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    posts = Task.query.all()
    return {'posts': [{'id': post.id, 'title': post.title, 'body': post.description} for post in posts]}


@app.route('/tasks/<title>/<description>', methods=['POST'])
def put_task(title, description):
    post = Task(title=title, description=description)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'New user added'
```

Comment: Ну это совершенно нормальная питоновская строка. Русские символы и правда в юникоде записываются. Где вы в таком виде получаете `json`, я не совсем понимаю?

Comment: @CrazyElf забыл уточнить, что так оно выглядит именно на сайте, когда я отправляю GET запрос (в консоли python кириллица выводится нормально)

Comment: Что такое "выглядит на сайте" - снова непонятно. Что вы делаете, чтобы увидеть эту строку, куда смотрите?

Comment: @CrazyElf Я пишу в адресной строке браузера "http://127.0.0.1:5000/tasks", на сайте по этому адресу и выводится список постов (метод @get_tasks())